# display 1st data only from column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column called bl_year in table XYZ, in bl_year column data is stored like :

```
June 2016
June 2016
June 2016
July 2016
August 2016
August 2016
August 2016
August 2016
```

When I am retrieving data its giving full list like above, but I want to show only 1 row from that month and year EX:

```
June 2016
July 2016
August 2016
```

I hope u will understand, I used LIMIT but its showing just one, i need to retrieve like

```
June 2016
July 2016
August 2016
```

Thanks,

```
Edit :
<div class="text-box">
                <h1>Blog Archive</h1>
                <?php 
                    $query1 = "SELECT es_id, bl_year, bl_created_by FROM blog WHERE bl_status = 'Approved' ORDER BY bl_year DESC";
                    $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
                            while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {

                            $bl_year = $row1['bl_year'];

                ?>
                <ul>
                    <li><?=$bl_year;?></li>
                </ul>
                <? } ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: I have just added query which i m using, i m not expert in php

Comment: If you were listing only that **ONE** single field or that one field and other fields with **REPEATED** values, you could use the key word **`DISTINCT`** in order to return distinct (non repeated) **FULL ROWS**. Please provide more sample data to enable us better assist you.

Comment: After you edit your question , are you sure what result you realll want?
If there is two different **es_id** with same **bl_year**?

Comment: @Arvind, check my ans

Answer (score 0):

I think you need **GROUP BY**

```
SELECT es_id, bl_year, bl_created_by FROM blog WHERE bl_status = 'Approved'
 GROUP BY es_id, bl_year, bl_created_by ORDER BY bl_year DESC"
```

Simple explanation ,GROUP BY usually cooperates with  **aggregate function** like count() :

```
SELECT COUNT(es_id), bl_year FROM blog GROUP BY bl_year
```

this gets count of total blogs in same bl_year

You need to include both **es_id**, **bl_created_by** column in GROUP BY clause because they don't work with aggregate function, if you don't, it can't tell which value to present in these columns, they may be different .

Or another present that work with  **GROUP_CONCAT**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(es_id), bl_year FROM blog WHERE bl_status = 'Approved'
GROUP BY es_id, bl_year ORDER BY bl_year DESC"
```

This will gets result like

```
 es_ids    |  bl_year
----------------------------
 24,25,26  |  July 2016
----------------------------
 21,22,23  |  June 2016
```

Comment: es_id will be different but month/year can be same, es_id is member_id, so any number of members can add and in same month and year

Comment: Not really sure what 'add' mean ... so "21(es_id )  June 2016"  "22(es_id )  June 2016" is availible? If yes ,I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT columns
FROM table_name
WHERE where_conditions
DISTINCT can Removes duplicate values
```

Example:
    You can us SELECT DISTINCT bl_year 
              FROM table_name WHERE where_conditions

Answer (score 0):

The `DISTINCT` `keyword` can be used to return only distinct (different) values

Syntax

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name FROM table_name;
```

In your case your query should be like

```
SELECT DISTINCT bl_year FROM XYZ;
```

Dont use `limit` it will only show how many `rows` you want from your `table`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct(es_id), bl_year, bl_created_by FROM blog WHERE bl_status = 'Approved' ORDER BY bl_year DESC
```

use distinct function... It merges all similar records in the table where distinct is applied

Answer (score 0):

Change the query in this way

```
SELECT MIN(es_id),bl_year, bl_created_by FROM blog WHERE bl_status = 'Approved' GROUP BY bl_year LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

The DISTINCT keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score -1):

mysql :

```
select distinct `you_row` from `your_table`
```